# google.maps.places.Autocomplete does not return some correct establishment addresses

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

The Google places (*google.maps.places.Autocomplete*) class that is available to use by linking an input box into a drop down list to display addresses from is causing me trouble when searching for establishments

I can generate this issue on the Google example page as well at:

[google places example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

I use this feature in my code much like the example above by including a reference to the places API:

```
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem seems to be mainly around [Establishments].  But not just any establishments.  It only occurs on some now and again.

The one I have particular issue with at the moment is when I type in the Name **United campervan rentals**, and select the resulting drop-down.  The address that is returned in the autocomplete.getPlace() command is not address I would expect.  The address returned is the middle of the bounds set when creating the autocomplete object.

However as per maps.google.co.nz, I an expecting an address of **3 Kingsford Smith Place**.

I've tried it in a number of browsers including IE 8, 9, Chrome, FF 3.6.  All produce the same result.  I've also tried at different times of the day and the same result.

I had posted this on the Google API forum but read an article that they are moving their Q&A to SO, so as long as I add the appropriate tags someone may be able to offer some sort of insight. I'm really hoping this is the case.  Cheers.

Comment: I've seen this problem popup just now testing with IE9.  I haven't been able to reproduce it on chrome or firefox.  What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: From memory I believe it was FF 3.6 I was using.  I think I may have tried it IE 9 as well and got the same symptons.

Comment: Somebody in our team just reproduced this on chrome too.  I suspect it's a timing issue; hitting submit before the place_changed event is fired.  I am adding a waiting mechanism before submit to see if the problem disappears.

Comment: I've waited a while (like 10sec) for the place_changed event to fire and it didn't occur.  Hope you have more luck than me.  I have not re-tested it in a while but our customers haven't said anything yet (although doesn't mean it isn't still happening).  Might try testing again after what you have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who reads this I logged an issue on the [gmaps API issue site](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) and after a few days the issue was cleared as fixed.  This also resolved the question.